# How do I link an already existing domain to a Windows Server 2019 VPS

Tags: django, nginx, vps, windows-server-2019, waitress

I have a Django project running with Nginx and Waitress on my Windows VPS. I want to make it accessible to the public with a domain name. I am completely clueless on how to go about it, although I have pointed my domain's A record to the Public IP address of the VPS. To be specific, I am running a Windows Server 2019 on the Gcloud platform.

Comment: is your port 80 open to accept request?

Comment: what do you mean by Gcloud platform, is it google cloud platform? did you bought a domain name? and can you access the web application from any browser if you wrote the public IP address?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri The port 80 of the nginx server serves as a gateway to load my django static files. The port 80 listens to the requests from my django server.

Comment: @OmarAl-Howeiti i mean Google cloud platform, i have a domain name already bought, although i have edited the A record such that it point's to the public ip address of my VPS, it's still not accessible. Also, trying to navigate to the public IP address of the VPS returns nothing.

Comment: did you add the domain name to the hosts file in Windows server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and make sure your VPS firewall settings are such that it allows request from public site at Port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to do it. I edited my Windows Server 2019 VPS firewall and added a port inbound rule, enabling request from remote clients on port 80 which is the port my nginx server serves from. @AnirudhBargi i guess i didn't understand your initial question. Enabling port 80 to accept request was the solution all along. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help :) a have added a crisp answer, if that is it.. please mark is as correct answer. :)